# Training a pre-cropped set with dlib simple_object_detector

Tags: python, object-detection, dlib

I'm trying to generate a simple object detector for the using the `dlib.simple_object_detector()` for python. The object for recognition is human faces acquired from the left side.

These human face profiles are pre-cropped, i.e. the images available to me only contain the profiles and not the body nor any background.

I have created a script for generating the necessary `.xml` file containing the image information where the bounding box is similar to the image size;
the structure of the file is identical to the one produces by the `imglab` tool as shown in the `dlib` examples.

When the detector is trained, the result cannot be generalized to images in the wild, i.e. when I try to detect facial profiles in some photos I've taken the bounding boxes generated are either missing or not good.

So, here are my questions:

1. In the `.xml` files I have input the entire path leading to each image rather than running the detector from the image path. Does that have an effect on the training process? Also, I have not included a label to the images.
2. Is there a way to use such a dataset to produce a detector or is it necessary to have a dataset with more background information for the objects of detection i.e. including some parts for the body and the background?
3. If more background information is required, does it need to be natural or could I just integrate the cropped facial profiles into some random images and run the detection?
4. Finally, do the bounding boxes need to be rectangles of the same size and/or aspect ratios?

Comment: Please can you add the code that you've tried?

Comment: options = dlib.simple_object_detector_training_options()
options.add_left_right_image_flips=False
options.C=12
options.be_verbose = True
options.num_threads=4
import time
start_time=time.time()
xmlpath=...
dlib.train_simple_object_detector(xmlPath,"C:\\Users\\smont\\Desktop\\Python\\FaceDetect\\DetPred\\profile_left_detector.svm",options)
print("---%s seconds ---" %(time.time()-start_time))

predPath='C:\\Users\\smont\\Desktop\\Python\\FaceDetect\\DetPred\\profile_left_detector.svm'
print("\nTraining accuracy:{}".
      format(dlib.test_simple_object_detector(xmlPath,predPath)))